# C++ Logic Errors; Can't Reason this out in my head:

Tags: c++, function, recursion, logic

This is less of a code error and more of a logic error, I was hoping you guys could help nonetheless.

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int recursivefunction(int NbProducts, int NbPlates, int prevlevel, int currentlevel, int * thearray ) {
    //cout << currentlevel; //debug
    currentlevel = (prevlevel + 1); prevlevel = prevlevel + 1;
    if(prevlevel = 0) { currentlevel = 0; }  //only ensures that the FIRST run has no issues with negatives
    while(thearray[currentlevel] < (NbProducts - NbPlates + 1)) {
            thearray[currentlevel] = thearray[currentlevel] + 1;
            if(currentlevel = NbPlates) {
                    cout << thearray[0] << thearray[1] << thearray[2] << endl;  //debug, do something to test full program
                    }
                    else recursivefunction(NbProducts, NbPlates, prevlevel, currentlevel, thearray );
            }
}
int main() {
    int NbProducts = 6, NbPlates = 3, prevlevel = 0, currentlevel = 0;
    int thearray[3] = {1, 2, 3};
//      cout << thearray[1]; //debug
         recursivefunction (NbProducts, NbPlates, prevlevel, currentlevel, thearray);
 }
```

what I'm trying to get it to do is recursively (I need this method for something to come later) output every combination of the array (3 elements) from 1 to NbProducts with NO REPEATS.

I just get:

```
133
133
133
133
```

no matter what, any ideas?

Comment: `recursivefunction` is not a good name for a function. What does it do?

Comment: it will run through an optimization of sorts; this is just getting the recursion going right. The actual program will have much more conveniently-named variables and functions.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation may do what you're looking for.  Example: http://ideone.com/S6uKML